# Can ALL events be listened to in more than one way?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Are are three "proper" ways to listen for events. In this example, we are listening for the `load` event:

```
1.  <body onload="doSomething();">
2.  document.body.onload = doSomething;
3.  document.body.addEventListener('load', doSomething);
```

Can **all** JavaScript events be listened to in all three of these ways?

Or are there events which are **only** dispatched (the third line), and cannot be "listened" to as an event attribute (the first line) or as a property of the element (the second line)? Or vice versa, are never dispatched, but only have settable "callback" properties?

Comment: Nope. E.g. the `devicelight` event is only triggered on `window`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/devicelight (I just picked that one because it's funny).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can **all** JavaScript events be listened to in all three of these ways?

No.

Some events in JavaScript are triggered on objects that are not part of the DOM, so there is no way to add an inline attribute in HTML when there is no HTML.

For example, [`MessageEvent`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MessageEvent) for WebSockets, and [`ProgressEvent`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ProgressEvent) for XmlHttpRequests.

There is a reference list of possible `on(eventname)` attributes in the [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#global-attributes):

> - onabort
> - onblur*
> - oncancel
> - oncanplay
> - oncanplaythrough
> - onchange
> - onclick
> - onclose
> - oncontextmenu
> - oncuechange
> - ondblclick
> - ondrag
> - ondragend
> - ondragenter
> - ondragexit
> - ondragleave
> - ondragover
> - ondragstart
> - ondrop
> - ondurationchange
> - onemptied
> - onended
> - onerror*
> - onfocus*
> - oninput
> - oninvalid
> - onkeydown
> - onkeypress
> - onkeyup
> - onload*
> - onloadeddata
> - onloadedmetadata
> - onloadstart
> - onmousedown
> - onmouseenter
> - onmouseleave
> - onmousemove
> - onmouseout
> - onmouseover
> - onmouseup
> - onmousewheel
> - onpause
> - onplay
> - onplaying
> - onprogress
> - onratechange
> - onreset
> - onresize*
> - onscroll*
> - onseeked
> - onseeking
> - onselect
> - onshow
> - onsort
> - onstalled
> - onsubmit
> - onsuspend
> - ontimeupdate
> - ontoggle
> - onvolumechange
> - onwaiting
>
> The attributes marked with an asterisk have a different meaning when specified on body elements as those elements expose event handlers of the Window object with the same names.

Regarding how events are handled on non-DOM objects, each feature has its own specification and API. Each feature is therefore subject to change along with the standard inconsistencies between browsers.

Comment: That makes sense for HTML attributes, but do those non-DOM-Elements that dispatch events all at least have "settable callback properties"? (I'm not sure if there is a proper name for those; line two in my example code)

Comment: @IQAndreas: That depends on the API of that object.